# Use android phone as a "3G to wifi" forwarding device, feasible?hints pls

Tags: android, networking, tcp, wifi, 3g

I would like to have my "computer A" (internet) connected to the android phone via 3G network (TCP,internet),

while the android phone is connected to the local wifi(no internet).
I have "another computer B" also connected to the local wifi(no internet).

How to make computer A and computer B able communicate to each other directly?

Give me some hints.. Thanks!!

update info 1:
the computer B has to connect to the local wifi network

update info 2:
One solution in my mind is to develop a small utility application simply forward all incoming packets (from 3G) to dedicated ip in local wifi. feasible?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to install one of the tethering apps which turn your android device into a hotspot which computer B can connect to (If I understand the question correctly).

Comment: thank you wojci. but the computer B is required to connect to the local existing wifi network. (B also communicates to other computers in the LAN)

Comment: Your android phone will hand out IP addresses to clients (DHCP). So you can have computer B and C etc. connected to this wireless network created by your phone. You can also use a wifi router as a repeater for this network.

Comment: some of the computers do not have wifi adapters (some of them are dedicated server.) I think what I need is a NAT service on the android phone.. something like port forwarding...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode) can be used as inspiration. You can use openwrt in client mode to connect a wired network to your existing wireless one (your android phone in this case).